# Nested interval property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a non empty set and let $\mathcal X=\{\mathcal X_i:i\in\mathbb R^+\cup\{0\}\}$ while $\mathcal X_i\subset X$ and $\mathcal X_j\subsetneq\mathcal X_i$ whenever $j>i$. Isn't that $\bigcap\{\mathcal X_i:i\in\mathbb R^+\cup\{0\}\}=\emptyset$ ?

If it is correct, whether the stronger statement $\bigcap\{\mathcal X_i:i\in\mathbb N\}=\emptyset$ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. Let $X=\Bbb R$ and consider $\mathcal X_i=\left[0,1+\frac1i\right)$ for $i>0$ and $\mathcal X_0=[0,\infty).$ For $j>i>0$ we have $\frac1j<\frac1i$, so $\mathcal X_j\subsetneq\mathcal X_i$, and clearly $\mathcal X_j\subsetneq\mathcal X_0$ for $j>0$, but $\bigcap_{i\ge0}\mathcal X_i=[0,1].$ Incidentally, we also have $\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}\mathcal X_i=[0,1]$.